# What kind of failures can be explained by this fix?

Tags: repair, networking

My Dell PowerConnect 2324 is normally plugged in 24/7. At some point it stopped working (no connectivity, power light out) and I disconnected it from the network and power. Recently I opened it up and started to test it with a digital multimeter:

[image: Disassembled Dell PowerConnect 2324]

Initially I checked the 5V supply directly from the AC converter. This was accurate within 5% but the power light was still off.

There are three circles printed on the board (bottom semicircle shaded white, top half empty/PCB) with a positive and ground contact. These look like they could be test points, so I next measured voltage at these points. Initially all three showed 0.00V. I thought this was odd because one of them was very close to the power connection. I tried again at the closest circle to the power connector and saw a flicker of 5V decreasing quickly to around 3V and then 0V again. I tried the other two circles and found 0V again. Back to the first one: steady 5V. Second one: steady 3.33V; third: steady 2.5V. I looked at the front and the power light was on. The device now functions properly again:

[image: Working LEDs on Dell PowerConnect 2324]

Can someone explain what could have happened and how it was fixed?

Comment: A loose wire or bad solder joint seems like the most likely explanation.

Comment: The device was not touched between working and breaking. When "repairing" it I hardly moved the inner board or connections, excepting the (sturdy) connectors between: AC/DC converter and main board; main board and front panel. After re-attaching it was still not working until the multimeter was connected a few times.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty confident that attaching the multimeter to the test points didn't fix it - so I don't see any other possibility except an intermittent fault of some sort.

Comment: This three "points" are not signal test points, but alignment marks. They help to align the soldering paste mask. You usually find them in the edges, and having only three of them  ensures the correct orientation. Sometimes, you also find smaller ones near ICs with many small pins to align the IC during placement (there is one above and one below the fat realtec IC on your PCB). __EDIT: Forget about my comment - you're speaking about the three not mounted ELKOs.__

Comment: @sweber What you're talking about is called a fiducial, and they're not required for aligning stencils, but rather for pick and place positioning.

Comment: @NickJohnson Our manufacturer asked for them also to align the stencil. But you're right, if they are used for aligning the stencil, they should be tinned after soldering.

Answer (score 3):

Dry solder joints most likely - you poking around with the multimeter brought them back into contact.  It's likely pins of those through-hole components in the top-left area of the green PCB.  But it probably won't stay working for long.  You should unscrew the big green PCB, flip it over, & re-solder all the through-hole components around that power-supply connector (connector, caps, coil).

Comment: Would you still do this if they looked "clean" and had connectivity to the next point(s)?

Comment: @SamBrightman probably not much point doing them all. Look for ones which are questionable (or post a close-up picture of the back of the board). The other thing to check is to try wiggling the cable that runs from the power supply if that causes the power to go off it's more likely a loose connection in one of the sockets.

Comment: unless you know what you're looking for, i'd at least re-touch each of those thru-hole pins (<20 pins, it'll only take a minute). & as @Tom said, it's possibly the cable from the power-supply too.